Why is React Native geolocation not getting my current longitude and lattitude?
Why is the Geolocation library not getting my current longitude and lattitude, instead it keeps showing the default  Latitude: 37.421998333333335, Longitude: -122.084, help fix the issue, I have tried everything and done the configurations needed. It's same issue when I use getCurrentPosition instead of watchPosition.
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, ActivityIndicator, PermissionsAndroid, Platform, AppState } from "react-native";
import MapView, { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io.connect('http://192.168.43.64:5000');

function MapRoute () {
    const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
    const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    const getUserCurrentLocation = () => {
        Geolocation.watchPosition(
            (position) => {
                console.log("Current position:", position);
                console.log("Latitude:", position.coords.latitude);
                console.log("Longitude:", position.coords.longitude);
                setLocation(position.coords);
                setLoading(false);
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log("Geolocation error:", error);
                setErrorMsg(error.message);
                setLoading(false);
            },
            { 
                enableHighAccuracy: true, 
                timeout: 15000, 
                maximumAge: 0, 
                distanceFilter: 10, // Update location when device moves 10 meters 
            }
        );
    };

    const requestLocationPermission = async () => {
        try {
            const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
                PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                {
                    title: 'Location Permission',
                    message: 'This app needs access to your location.',
                    buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
                    buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
                    buttonPositive: 'OK',
                }
            );
            if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
                console.log('Location permission granted');
                getUserCurrentLocation();
                setLoading(false);
            } else {
                console.log('Location permission denied');
                setErrorMsg('Location permission denied');
                setLoading(false);
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.warn(err);
            setLoading(false);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            requestLocationPermission();
        } else {
            getUserCurrentLocation();
        }

        const subscription = AppState.addEventListener("change", (nextAppState) => {
            if (nextAppState === "active") {
                getUserCurrentLocation();
            }
        });

        return () => {
            subscription.remove();
        };
    }, []);

    socket.on('connect', () => { 
        console.log("driver socket id is", socket.id);
        socket.emit("driver-connect", 
            {
                driverAccountId: 2, 
                driverSocketId: socket.id,
                companyUnderAccountId: 1 
            }
        );
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        if (location !== null) {
            socket.emit("driver-current-location", 
                { 
                    driverSocketId: socket.id, 
                    driverLocation: location, 
                    driverAccountId: 2, 
                    companyUnderAccountId: 1 
                }
            );
        }
    }, [location, socket]);

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {loading ? (
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="blue" />
            ) : (
                <>
                    {location ? (
                        <>
                            <Text>React native map <Text>latitude {location.latitude} longitude {location.longitude}</Text></Text>
                            <MapView
                                style={styles.map}
                                region={{
                                    latitude: location.latitude,
                                    longitude: location.longitude,
                                    latitudeDelta: 0.01,
                                    longitudeDelta: 0.01,
                                }}
                            >
                                <Marker
                                    coordinate={{
                                        latitude: location.latitude,
                                        longitude: location.longitude,
                                    }}
                                    title={"Testing"}
                                />
                            </MapView>
                        </>
                    ) : (
                        <Text>No location available</Text>
                    )}
                </>
            )}
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1
    },
    map: {
        flex: 1
    }
});


export default MapRoute;


Where do you try your code? In real device or simulator?

I tested the code on Emulator. Isn't there a way I can test on Emulator that it will work?

Emulator have custom setting to simulate the GPS location. Please setup refer to the target platform simulator. Android/ iOS
